Sobolev regularity for the Poisson problem with discontinuous coefficient
Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ be the weak solution of the Poisson problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\nabla \cdot (\mu \nabla u) = f & \text{in } \Omega \\
u = 0 & \text{in } \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
\mu = 
\begin{cases}
\mu_1 & \text{in } \Omega_1 \\
\mu_2 & \text{in } \Omega_2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
with $\Omega_1 \subset \Omega$ and $\Omega_2 = \Omega \setminus \Omega_1$.
Under which hypothesis on the smoothness of $\Omega$ and $\Omega_1$ can we say that for any $k \geq -1$, $f|_{\Omega_1} \in H^{k}(\Omega_1)$ and $f|_{\Omega_2} \in H^{k}(\Omega_2)$ imply that $u|_{\Omega_1} \in H^{k+2}(\Omega_1)$ and $u|_{\Omega_2} \in H^{k+2}(\Omega_2)$?
In Babuska 1970 "The finite element method for elliptic equations with discontinuous coefficients", Theorem 1.1 states that this is true when both $\Omega$ and $\Omega_1$ have $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ boundary. However, is it possible to weaken this assumption? In particular, is it possible to extend this result (with additional assumptions, if necessary) to the case of polygonal boundaries?

If the coefficient is discontinuous, then the first derivative of $u$ is discontinuous across the interface between $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. Imho $\nabla u$ cannot be in $H^1$ then, and $u$ cannot be in $H^2$. No matter how smooth $\Omega$ and $f$ is.

Thank you for the answer. However, I am not asking that $u$ is globally $H^{k+2}$, but just that its restriction to the two subdomains is in $H^{k+2}$. I have rephrased the question so that my question is more clear.
